# How to lowercase one specific letter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, uppercase

This is the case: i'm working on a Wordpress theme and all the titles (h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6) on a page needs to be in uppercase except for one letter, the letter: **i**. This letter needs to be in lowercase. Example: THiS LETTER NEEDS TO BE iN LOWERCASE.

I'm looking for a solution where i don't need to type the uppercase letters in WP admin manually, because I don't want to store it this way in the database. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to do. Which letter should be lowercase? Is it the same in every heading? Is it based on position, a specific character, the word it is in, etc?

Comment: I don't understand why it's not specific enough. All your questions are answered in my description. Anyway, i've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the elements you need to update using `document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")`, which returns an array-like `NodeList` of the elements. You then [loop through it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) processing each element.

You can get and set their text using their `textContent` property. (It's more complicated if they may have decendant elements, like `<h1>Hi <em>there</em></h1>`.)

You can change all characters in a string other than `i` to upper case by using `replace`:

```
element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(/[a-hj-z]+/g, str => str.toLocaleUpperCase());
```

If you need to handle characters outside the English-centric regex above, one simple option is to use `[^i]`:

```
element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(/[^i]+/g, str => str.toLocaleUpperCase());
```

Using `toLocaleUpperCase` on something like `1` just returns it unchanged.